# Git Terminal Unable to find SSH key, even after successfully generating it

Tags: git, github, ssh

I recently started trying to learn web development on the Odin project. It had me set up an environment to run linux.

I got to the stage of generating an SSH key to connect to Github.
The command window successfully generates a key, but then no matter what I try I Can't get it to show me to key to actually put into Github.

After an hour I attempted to run the setup in Windows. And the exact same issue is occurring. It can generate a key, but even when I can see the `.ssh` file, nothing I do from anything I've seen online will actually let me copy it.
It always just returns that no such file or directory exists.

I've literally never used Git before so I have no idea what to do, but every help solution I've looked at online has failed.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show exactly what commands you're running and what messages they're printing. If you're running GUI programs, say exactly what you're doing. Don't paraphrase things.

Comment: I've tried both cat and clip

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to generate the key using command line:

```
ssh-keygen -P "" -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/github
```

Then you can:

```
cat ~/.ssh/github.pub
# or, on Windows
type ~/.ssh/github.pub
# from a Windows CMD
type %USERPROFILE%\.ssh\github.pub
```

You can then copy-paste the content of the public key to your GitHub SSH keys section of your profile.

Note: `~/.ssh/github.pub` does exist, provided you used the `-f ~/.ssh/github` parameter with `ssh-keygen`. The private key name (`github`) is used to infer the public key name (`github.pub`).

On Windows, `~` defaults to `%USERPROFILE%` (unless `%HOME%` is set explicitly)

Comment: That's exactly what I've been doing. It doesn't work.

Comment: @Adam OK (I didn't know what you did, because, as commented, you did paraphrased what happened instead of copying the exact command and output). Does the `cat ~/.ssh/github.pub` returns "No such file or directory"?